# Can I send a web call from WatchKit app using watchOS2?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, ios9, watchos-2

I want to send the web call directly from watch so that it would work even if parent iPhone app is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/), If you need see this [WWDC 2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-711/). It doesn't need companion app, Even, it can work without iPhone.